# Bubble label with googlevis

Tags: json, r, google-visualization

I want to hide label above bubble in my chart, what argument i have to add ?
Here is my script:

```
VehiculeFunction <- function(data, gamme, absciss, ordinate, label){

  if(absciss == "GMF.24"){
    my.data <- data[data$RANG_NITG_PROJET_K %in% c(1, 2, 3),]
  } else if(absciss == "Ratio.K") {
    my.data <- data[data$RANG_NITG_PROJET_C %in% c(1, 2, 3),]
  }
  my.data2 <- my.data[my.data$GAMME == gamme,]
  ma.col = rgb(red = 0.1,blue = 1,green = 0.1, alpha = 0.2)
  X <- my.data2[[absciss]] 
  Y <- my.data2[[ordinate]] 
  Z <- my.data2[[label]]
  PROJET <- my.data2$PROJET
  df <- data.frame(X,Y,Z,PROJET)
  plot(gvisBubbleChart(df, idvar = "Z", xvar = "X", yvar = "Y", sizevar = "Y", colorvar = "PROJET", options=list(width=1500, height=1500 ),
                   bubble="{textStyle:{color: 'none', fontName: 
                   <global-font-name>, fontSize: 
                   <global-font-size>}}")) 

}

VehiculeFunction(data.vehicule, gamme = "M1", "GMF.24", "Cout.24", "NITG")
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, after adding the bubble option !

Comment: Error in gvisBubbleChart(df, idvar = "Z", xvar = "X", yvar = "Y", sizevar = "SIZEVAR",  : 
  unused argument (bubble = "{textStyle:{color: 'none', fontName: \n

Comment: bubble should be in the list of `options`

Comment: If you don't supply any sample data, we can't run the code to see what you are seeing. Please read [how to make a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). This will make it easier for people to help you.